# Java "equivalent" to CSLA

Tags: c#, java, frameworks, business-objects, csla

I've read several chapters of the [CSLA](http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/) book and I like it, but being lately geared more towards Java, I'm looking for a Java-based equivalent. Does anybody know anything that comes close to *CSLA in Java*?

I would also settle for a good combination of other existing technologies that would achieve similar goals.

Comment: The question would be more interesting if you told us what CSLA is or what you want to do with it. And someone who didn't know CSLA but might know something equivalent or similar might be able to answer then as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not any framework available similar to CSLA.NET in Java.

Suraj Chandran in not correct.

Spring is an AOP framework and Hibernate is an OR-Mapper. Where, CSLA is a BusinessObject framework.

Answer (score 0):

No. AFAIK, as of know there is no port of CSLA to java, niether any equivalent. But a mix of Springframework with Hibernate can come a little bit closer.